# Probability for 2 players of getting the same number of heads when flipping 3 coins

Tags: probability

We each flip three fair coins. I offer to pay you 1 if we do not get the same amount of heads, if you agree to pay me 2 if we do (get the same amount of heads). Will you agree to play this game?

I'm not really sure how to even start this question, let alone get the answer.

Thanks

Comment: It seems relatively straightforward to tabulate, e.g. using the binomial theorem, the probability of outcomes (number of heads) for two independent players, and use this joint distribution to find your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability of getting only one head is $\frac{1}{8} ·3$, as the sequence with one head can be arranged in three different ways.

Similarly, the probability of getting two heads is $\frac{1}{8}·3$.

The probability of getting three heads is $\frac{1}{8}$. The probability of getting 0 heads is also $\frac{1}{8}$.

As the other person must get the same, we must square them. For example, the chance of both getting one head is $\left( \frac{1}{8} · 3 \right) ^2$ as we both must meet the same probability.

Then, the probability of getting the same number of heads is

$$\left( \frac{3}{8} \right) ^2+\left(\frac{3}{8} \right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{8} \right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{8} \right)^2= \frac{20}{64}= \frac{5}{16}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  What is the chance you get $0$ heads?  $1$ head?  $2, 3?$  The distribution for your friend is the same.  The chance you get the same number is the sum of the chances you both get $0$, you both get $1$, ...  Apply the addition and multiplication principles.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :

the **event1** of not getting the same amount of heads is the complementary of the **event2** of getting a different amount of heads.

For the game to be equitable the probability of the first event must be the half of the probability of the second event, that is 
$$P(1)= \frac{1}{3}. $$
(using the complementarity between $event1$ and $event2$.)

Now you play the game if $P(1)\leq \frac{1}{3}$, and equivalently $P(2)\geq \frac{2}{3}$. I assume that you are the one who got paid if event2 occurs, the formulation is not clear in the question.